# Flicker on fadein text hover

Tags: css, fadein, flicker

I have a simple fadein css... I'd like it so when you hover over text, the border-bottom fades in. However, when I hover, the text disappears briefly then fades in with the border, so it flickers. How do I get it so the text remains constant on hover and only the border fades in?

The CSS

```
.nav li a:hover{
border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
-webkit-animation: fadein .5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-moz-animation: fadein .5s; /* Firefox */
-ms-animation: fadein .5s; /* Internet Explorer */
-o-animation: fadein .5s; /* Opera */
animation: fadein .5s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Firefox */
@-moz-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Safari and Chrome */
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Internet Explorer */
@-ms-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Opera */
@-o-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```

The HTML

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li> <a href="#" role="button" aria-expanded="false">About</a></li>
  <li> <a href="#" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Services</a></li>
  <li> <a href="#" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Portfolio</a></li>
  <li> <a href="#" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Contact</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be a transition rather than an animation? This seems a complex way of going about things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the line `border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;` and instead add:

```
.nav li a {
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

and also change all of this:

```
from { opacity: 0; }
to   { opacity: 1; }
```

to

```
from { border-bottom-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); }
to   { border-bottom-color: rgba(0,0,0,1); }
```

See this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lmdt0nx6/) for reference.

Alternatively, as suggested in the comments by @Paulie_D you can also just do:

```
.nav li a {
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

.nav li a:hover{
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,1);
  -webkit-transition: border-bottom .4s ease;
  -moz-transition: border-bottom .4s ease;
  -ms-transition: border-bottom .4s ease;
  -o-transition: border-bottom .4s ease;
  transition: border-bottom .4s ease;
}
```

which obviously makes everything a lot easier.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hojqmkbm/) for the second version